# Connecting to php-script from Delphi app via HTTP-POST[Via Internet]

Tags: php, delphi, delphi-xe5

I've written a test php script located in a remote server of mine, and 
I am using Delphi code to do a Http_Post to that php file.

It works perfectly when I am doing it on a local server, but fails with a

> Socket Error #10061 - Connection Refused

error.

Here is the code I am using to do the Http Post :

```
function TForm1.doPost(Url : String): string;
var
  lHTTP: TIdHTTP;
  lParamList: TStringList;
begin
  lParamList := TStringList.Create;
  lParamList.Add('service_test=Testing Server');

  lHTTP := TIdHTTP.Create(nil);
  try
    Result := lHTTP.Post(Url, lParamList);
    prgView.StepIt;
  finally
    lHTTP.Free;
    lParamList.Free;
  end;
end;
```

The url is reachable fro, browser and other applications viz. [Tested with an android app with the same php script]

Url : http://pbcserver.dlinkddns.com/users/priyabrata/contest.php

Php Script :

```
if (isset($_POST["service_test"])){
    $val = $_POST["service_test"];
    if ($val == "Testing Server"){
        $response["Success"] = "1";
        echo (json_encode($response));
    }
    else{
        $response["Success"] = "0";
        echo (json_encode($response));
    }
}
else{
    $response["Success"] = "0";
    echo (json_encode($response));
}
```

> **New Observation** :
>
> When I run the app from within Delphi, the post doesn't work and get
>   the above error,however when I run the created .exe from Windows like
>   any other app, it works perfectly!

Comment: you have a space here `service_test=Testing Server` try it with `service_test=Testing%20Server` .

Comment: Doesn't help. Getting the same error.

Comment: without seeing the `Url` and the `php script`, it is difficult to help.

Comment: If you are using a firewall, you have given to your program permission to connect to your server? Can you turn off the firewall, to test ?

Comment: No firewalls are in place. As I said, android app can connect to this same script without any problem. *Url and Php scripts added to the main post

Comment: your `isset($_GET["..."]` will not work you doing a `HTTP.Post` .

Comment: It's my bad. I copied the php script from another test file, there it was $_GET. I did change it to $_POST in the test server. I've a new observation, added it to main thread

Comment: I can not connect to your server (via browser or delphi) . Getting a `Error: Network timeout

The server pbcserver.dlinkddns.com takes too long to post a response.

     The site could be temporarily unavailable, please try again later.
     If you can not access any other site, please check the network / Internet connection.
     If your computer or network is protected by a firewall or proxy, make sure that Firefox is permitted to access the Internet.`

Comment: Strange. I can acccess it via vrowser. will try later as you say

Comment: I also can't open your website. Even more. I can't even PING the server that is hosting your website. I'm gettin reply from PING "Destination net unreachable"

Comment: @SilverWarior unpingable HTTP servers are nothing uncommon as ICMP can be blocked for security reasons

Comment: http://www.downforeveryoneorjustme.com/pbcserver.dlinkddns.com says that the server is down

Comment: Thats pretty strange. This server is running in a VM in my machine, and I can access it.

Comment: Does the server has acces to internet? Can you open some web page from the server? It is possible that your server is only accessible from within the local network and I gues that your host computer and WM share the same local network.

Comment: No, I can open webpages from server. Its in a bridged mode[Virtual Box]. I  can access it via internet as well.

Comment: @Priyabrata : go to this site [showMyIP](https://www.whatismyip.com/my-ip-information) write your ip down. Power off your DSL Router or whatever, wait , Power On Router , go to `showMyIP` look at your ip,  I'm pretty sure it's not the same !!

Comment: I've a static ip @moskito-x It doesn't change. I knew this, how ever I did what you said above and it stays same